# Unit testing promise in AngularJS with Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

When I run this part of the test that follows, somehow it is halted at the line of `$rootScope.$digest()`with `DISCONNECTED no message in 10000ms` error.
Changing `browserNoActivityTimeout` params in karma.conf.js makes no difference.
What happened in my test code?

```
describe 'AuthService', ->
  # Initialize variables
  AuthService = $rootScope = undefined

  beforeEach module('app')

  beforeEach inject(($q, _$rootScope_, $localStorage, _AuthService_) ->
    AuthService = _AuthService_
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_
    spyOn(AuthService, "login").and.callFake(
      (loginEmail, loginPassword) ->
        $localStorage.apiKey = 'test'
        deferred = $q.defer()
        deferred.resolve({
          data: {
            apiKey: 'test'
            token: 'test'
          }
        })
        return deferred.promise
    )
  )

  #FIXME it should test promise
  #      Some reasons halt $rootScope.$digest()
  it 'let user login correctly', ->
    expect(AuthService.isLoggedIn()).toEqual(false)
    AuthService.login('test@example.com', 'Test1001').then(
      (response) ->
        expect(AuthService.isLoggedIn()).toEqual(true) 
    )
    $rootScope.$digest()
```

Comment: Ever found out what happened here? I'm encountering a similar issue when mocking a service.